# Получить выборочно таблицы из БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Всем привет.
Есть ли в EF возможность при существубщей БД (PgSQL)
Не тянуть ее всю целиком через Scaffold-DbContext.

А, например сделать модели 2 таблиц, создать контекст и через EF данные только этих 2 таблиц ?

Первый вариант который наклевывается - просто открыть соединение с БД и запросом получить нужные данные. Но хочется попрактиковаться с EF не загрязняя проект кучей не нужных классов для не нужных таблиц

Comment: Наличие моделей не означает подгрузку таблиц. Наличие моделей означает возможность строить запросы с использованием полей этих таблиц.

Comment: Да, можно. Нужные модели можно создать полностью вручную. А можно сгенерировать все подряд с помощью scaffold, после чего удалить ненужные. Но правильнее указать необходимые таблицы: [Specifying tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#specifying-tables) - документация - великая вещь.